# Complex grouping in Linq? C#.net

Tags: c#, linq

folks,

I got a couple interconnected entities:

```
public class MainObject {
    public Guid property1; //one-to-many relationship
    public Guid? property2;
    public int? property3;
    public List<PivorObject> PivotObjects; //one-to-many relationship
}

public PivotObject {
    public Guid property4; //one-to-many relationship
    public long property5;
    public long property6;
}
```

I need to group a `List<MainObject>` with the following criteria:

1. Same `property1` AND
2. Same `property2` AND
3. Same `property3` AND
4. Same `PivotObjects.FirstOrDefault(po => po.property5 == criterion1 && po.property6 == criterion2).Select(po => po.property4)` OR `PivotObjects.FirstOrDefault(po => po.property5 == criterion1 && po.property6 == criterion2) == null`

In the result I want to have as many piles of `MainObject` as it takes to separate the initial list by this combination. So where nullable types are null, they evaluate the same as other nulls.

Is there an elegant way to produce such a grouping?

I am asking about solutions besides groupby property1, inside the result group by property2, and so on. I am looking for something native that can spit out the piles I need. So possibly a dictionary with 4 keys or something of that sort.

Comment: Is this for LINQ to Objects, or "out of process" LINQ? Grouping by multiple properties is simple - just use `GroupBy` with an anonymous type (e.g. `new { mo.property1, mo.property2, mo.property3 }` but the complex fourth criterion may cause issues in something like LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Hi, Jon, there's lazy loading, so it will grab info from the database, but I'm not pushing anything back. All I want in the fourth key is guid from the appropriate `PivotObject` or null when there is no appropriate match. I cannot group by `PivotObject` itself because there's a many-to-one relationship between the `PivotObject` and the `MainObject`. I guess one way is group by the three criteria and then split the groups appropriately in a `foreach`.

Comment: By the time you're trying to do this grouping, has everything been loaded? (It doesn't help that your grouping appears to use `criterion1` and `criterion2` which haven't been defined...)

Comment: No, not everything. Only the initial `List<MainObject>` is loaded, If there are any entities it references, they are just references, needs to go back to database for use. I can use include statements. `criterion1` and `criterion2` don't really matter. The important part is that I need to group by `property4` when there is an appropriate PivotObject, and when there's no such object, they go in the "leftovers" pile or something like that.

Comment: Well you don't need the actual objects, presumably - the Guids should be enough, right? It sounds like you should be able to write a method to return an appropriate `PivotObject` or null, and group by that.

Comment: Right. I can just put a method in `MainObject`, which can return the appropriate result. That will work, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I missing something? Isn't it just:

```
var MainObject.GroupBy(m=>new { 
  m.Property1,
  m.Property2,
  m.Property3,
  m.PivotObjects.FirstOrDefault(po => po.property5 == criterion1 && po.property6 == criterion2)?.property4)
});
```

Comment: When `m.PivotObjects.FirstOrDefault(po => po.property5 == criterion1 && po.property6 == criterion2) == null`, addressing `property4` will throw null exception.